# LDAP-Error in Identity Server 4.6 when using user registration with "Ask password from user"

Tags: password-recovery, wso2-identity-server

I wanted to try the password-notification feature of the IS 4.6 but it throwing an exception.
I followed those links: 
https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Recover+with+Notification
http://cgchamath.blogspot.mx/2013/12/wso2-identity-server-user-creation-with.html

This is the error I am getting
[image]

Here is the Stacktrace

> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error
>   while persisting identity user data in to user store  at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore.store(UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore.java:81)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPostAddUser(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:420)
>     ... 124 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException:
>   One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported
>   by underlying LDAP.   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValues(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:874)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore.store(UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore.java:73)
>     ... 125 more Caused by:
>   javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16
>   - NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for     Modify Request
>           Object : 'uid=testUser,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
>               Modification[0]
>                   Operation :  replace
>                   Modification
>       http://wso2.org/claims/identity/passwordTimestamp: 1398394865706
>               Modification[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkaXa.png)
>                   Operation :  replace
>                   Modification
>       initials: false : ERR_04269 ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID http://wso2.org/claims/identity/passwordtimestamp does not exist!];
>   remaining name 'uid=testUser'     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3108)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1411)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:253)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:154)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValues(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:859)
>     ... 126 more

I can imagine that the application is generating a timestamp for the expiration of the password and tries to save in a field in the LDAP which is mapped by the combination:
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/passwordtimestamp -> nickName
This mapping is wrong obviously.
How can I force an adequate mapping so the process is saving the user in the right way (and hopefully sending the email after that ...)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem on this way solved:
I had to re-add the claim of the password time stamp, but with the correct uri:
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/passwordTimestamp

Also helpful was:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1200

The LDAP-error is fixed, but still it is not sending the email. But that is another issue